# Tabularx and multirow overflowing

Tags: tabularx, multirow

I am trying to span a row over two rows in a tabularx table with the following:

```latex
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline \\
        \textbf{Column1} & \textbf{Column2} & \textbf{Column3} & \textbf{Column4} \\ \hline
    Row1 & Text1 & \multirow{2}{*}{Spanning text that may need to be wrapped in the column} & 500 \\ \hline
    Row2 & Text2 & & 500\\ \hline 
    Row3 & Text3 & SomeOtherText & MoreText \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

However currently getting:
[image]

- The spanning text is overflowing
- A horizontal line is being drawn between the spanning cells
- Something strange with the lines around *"Column2"*, *"Column3"*, *"Column4"*

(compiling with `pdflatex`)

What is the **simplest** way to fix this...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should get you started:

[image]

`\multirow{*}` results in a cell that is as wide as its contents, hence the overflow. To get a multirow cell that is as wide as the surrounding column, use `\multirow{=}` instead.

To get rid of the horizontal line, use `\cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}` instead of the `\hline`.

To fix the column headers, remove the `\\`  after the first `\hline` command.

Once these changes are applied, you will notice the multirow text overflows into the third table row. This is due to the multirow text occupying 4 linew, while you only allowed it to span 2 table rows. To overcome this, I added `&&&\\`  to add two empty table rows.

> "The second case is when  the `\multirow` entry is taller than the
> surrounding normal rows. In that case the multirow text will stick out
> of its block. We must now enlarge the other rows, and that is
> something `\multirow` cannot do." (section "3.8  Dealing with tall
> entries", currently on page 13-15 of the `multirow` manual)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Column1} & \textbf{Column2} & \textbf{Column3} & \textbf{Column4} \\ \hline
    Row1 & Text1 & \multirow{4}{=}{Spanning text that may need to be wrapped in the column} & 500 \\ &&&\\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}
    
    Row2 & Text2 & & 500\\  &&&\\\hline 
    Row3 & Text3 & SomeOtherText & MoreText \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Since you asked for a more automated way of making sure a tall `\multirow` text does not overflow, even if it taller than the rows it spans, here is an approach based on the quite new `tabularray` package:

> "Second, it will enlarge row heights if the multirow cells have large
> height, therefore it always avoids vertical overflow." (from section
> "1.4 Multirow Cells", currently on page 4-5 of the `tabularray`
> manual)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines, colspec={XXXX}}
        \textbf{Column1} & \textbf{Column2} & \textbf{Column3} & \textbf{Column4} \\
    Row1 & Text1 & \multirow{2}{=}{Spanning text that may need to be wrapped in the column} & 500 \\ 
    Row2 & Text2 & & 500\\  
    Row3 & Text3 & SomeOtherText & MoreText \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Personally, I would work around this issue by adjustig the column widths. Since only one column contains longer texts, while all others contain just single words, I would change teh column specifiers of columns 1, 2 and 4 to `l` instead of `X`. This would result in the following MWE and output, in which you don't have to worry about overflowing `\multirow` text and ymore, since it only occupies two rows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|l|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Column1} & \textbf{Column2} & \textbf{Column3} & \textbf{Column4} \\ \hline
    Row1 & Text1 & \multirow{2}{=}{Spanning text that may need to be wrapped in the column} & 500 \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}

    Row2 & Text2 & & 500\\ \hline 
    Row3 & Text3 & SomeOtherText & MoreText \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines, colspec={llXl}}
        \textbf{Column1} & \textbf{Column2} & \textbf{Column3} & \textbf{Column4} \\
    Row1 & Text1 & \multirow{2}{=}{Spanning text that may need to be wrapped in the column} & 500 \\ 
    Row2 & Text2 & & 500\\  
    Row3 & Text3 & SomeOtherText & MoreText \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand! Little lost at *This is due to the multirow text occupying 4 linew*. Is there a more automatic method than adding empty rows ?

Comment: As far as I know, unfortunately not, at least not with `multirow`. The `multirow` documentation als explicitly states "The second case is when the `\multirow` entry is taller than the surrounding normal rows. In that case the multirow text will stick out of its block. We must now enlarge the other rows, and that is something `\multirow` cannot do." (page 13-15)  For this particular table, I would recommend using `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|l|}`. With this alternative you should be able to get away with the `\multirow` occupying just 2 rows, hence no need for added, empty rows.

Comment: @kaleidawave: I have just updated my answer to also include an apporach based on the new `tabularray` package which attempts to avoid overflowing `\multirow` contents. Probably this approach is also interesting for you.